# Difference between DataFrame API methods vs Storing DF as table

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

What is the difference between saving the `DF as temp table` then process using SQL queries and directly accessing the `DF API methods`?

**For example:**

```
df.registerTempTable("tablename")
sqlCtx.sql("select column1 from tablename where column2='value2' group by column1")
```

and this

```
df.where($"column2"==="value2").groupBy($"column1").select($"column1")
```

Is there any performance difference between these two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark DataFrames: registerTempTable vs not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926785/spark-dataframes-registertemptable-vs-not)