# How to get this using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
**DF1**   **DF2**            **output_DF**
120 D        A               120  null  A
120 E        B               120  null  B
125 F        C               120  null  C
             D               120   D    D
             E               120   E    E
             F               120  null  F
             G               120  null  G
             H               120  null  H
                             125  null  A
                             125  null  B
                             125  null  C
                             125  null  D
                             125  null  E
                             125   F    F
                             125  null  G
                             125  null  H
```

From dataframe 1 and 2 need to get the final output dataframe in spark-shell.
where A,B,C,D,E,F are in date format(yyyy-MM-dd) & 120,125 are the ticket_id's column where there are thousands of ticket_id's.
I just extracted one out of it here.

Comment: You can look into the `df.join()` function and possibly `df.na.fill()` as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate please...!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining Spark dataframes on the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343625/joining-spark-dataframes-on-the-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the expected result you can use `df.join()` and `df.na.fill()` (as mentioned in comments), like this:

**For Spark 2.0+**

```
val resultDF = df1.select("col1").distinct.collect.map(_.getInt(0)).map(id => df1.filter(s"col1 = $id").join(df2, df1("col2") === df2("value"), "right").na.fill(id)).reduce(_ union _)
```

**For Spark 1.6**

```
val resultDF = df1.select("col1").distinct.collect.map(_.getInt(0)).map(id => df1.filter(s"col1 = $id").join(df2, df1("col2") === df2("value"), "right").na.fill(id)).reduce(_ unionAll _)
```

It will give you the following result -

```
+---+----+-----+
|120|null|    A|
|120|null|    B|
|120|null|    C|
|120|   D|    D|
|120|   E|    E|
|120|null|    F|
|120|null|    G|
|120|null|    H|
|125|null|    A|
|125|null|    B|
|125|null|    C|
|125|null|    D|
|125|null|    E|
|125|   F|    F|
|125|null|    G|
|125|null|    H|
+---+----+-----+
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: If there are N number of ID’s in the column which has values only for few dates, when joined with the unique date DF2 we need to get the above output_DF. Edited the question for more clarity.
@himanshulllTian

Comment: @maduri - I have updated my answer according to edited question.

Comment: <console>:65: error: value union is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @maduri - I have updated my answer according to different Spark versions.

Comment: No himashulllTian. Its printing the column names for all the rows, no data.

Comment: @maduri - Can you share the code that you are using?

Comment: Hi himanshulllTian, got the output using this:
    val dates = comp_data.select("comparative_date").distinct
    val dates_str = dates.collect().map(_.getString(0))
    val tic_dis = seldata.select("ticket_id").distinct
    val tic_unique = tic_dis.map(x=> (x(0).toString,dates_str))
    val tic_unique_DF = tic_unique.toDF("ticket","date")
    val unique_ticket = tic_unique_DF.withColumn("date1", explode(tic_unique_DF("date")))
    val unique_ticket1 = unique_ticket.select("ticket","date1")

Comment: val q = comp_data.join(unique_ticket1, comp_data("ticket_id")===unique_ticket1("ticket") && comp_data("comparative_date")===unique_ticket1("date1"), "rightouter")
val joined_df = q.join(rep_data, q("ticket")===rep_data("rep_ticket_id"),"rightouter")

Answer (score 0):

Full join of possible values, then left join with original dataframe:

```
import hiveContext.implicits._
val df1Data = List((120, "D"), (120, "E"), (125, "F"))
val df2Data = List("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
val df1 = sparkContext.parallelize(df1Data).toDF("id", "date")
val df2 = sparkContext.parallelize(df2Data).toDF("date")

// get unique ID: 120, 125
val uniqueIDDF = df1.select(col("id")).distinct()
val fullJoin = uniqueIDDF.join(df2)
val result = fullJoin.as("full").join(df1.as("df1"), col("full.id") === col("df1.id") && col("full.date") === col("df1.date"), "left_outer")

val sorted = result.select(col("full.id"), col("df1.date"), col("full.date")).sort(col("full.id"), col("full.date"))
sorted.show(false)
```

output:

```
+---+----+----+
|id |date|date|
+---+----+----+
|120|null|A   |
|120|null|B   |
|120|null|C   |
|120|D   |D   |
|120|E   |E   |
|120|null|F   |
|120|null|G   |
|120|null|H   |
|125|null|A   |
|125|null|B   |
|125|null|C   |
|125|null|D   |
|125|null|E   |
|125|F   |F   |
|125|null|G   |
|125|null|H   |
+---+----+----+
```

Sorting here just for show the same result, can be skipped.