# How to compare two dates from two DF without matching index?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
df1
  USERID    DATE
     1       1/1/2018
     1       1/2/2018
     1       1/3/2018
     2       1/2/2018
     2       1/3/2018
     3       1/3/2018

df2
  USERID    DATE
     1       1/1/2018        
     2       1/2/2018         
     3       1/3/2018
```

I want to compare `date` from `df2` to `df1` that belongs to the same `USERID` to tell if the row in `df1` also exists in `df2`

```
Result:
  USERID      DATE       Exists
     1       1/1/2018     True
     1       1/2/2018     False
     1       1/3/2018     False
     2       1/2/2018     True
     2       1/3/2018     False
     3       1/3/2018     True
```

I want to do the equivalent of
`np.where((df1['DATE'] == df2['DATE']), True, False)`
but an error returns right now `Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) :

```
# create a new column 
df2['Exists'] = True

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['USERID','DATE'],how='outer').fillna(False)

  USERID    DATE    Exists
0   1   1/1/2018    True
1   1   1/2/2018    False
2   1   1/3/2018    False
3   2   1/2/2018    True
4   2   1/3/2018    False
5   3   1/3/2018    True
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to do a [left join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) and then displaying a new column where `df2` is null.

Below is an example adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40356825/865883) as well as [this post](http://www.learnbymarketing.com/1100/pyspark-joins-by-example/):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Alias the columns here, to prevent column name collision
df1_alias = df1.alias("first")
df2_alias = df2.alias("second")

# Left join on df1.id = df2.id and df1.date = df2.date
result = df1_alias.join(df2_alias, (df1_alias.id == df2_alias.id) & (df1_alias.date == df2_alias.date), how='left')

# Create a column called 'exists' and set it to true if there's a value defined for df2
result = result.withColumn('exists', F.col("second.id").isNotNull())

# Display just df1 values and the exists column
result.select([F.col("first.id"), F.col("first.name"), F.col("exists")]).show()
```