# How to compare few columns of a dataframe with its other columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 8 columns in a dataframe in spark,

1. Name_a,
2. status_a,
3. date_a,
4. ID_a,
5. Name_b,
6. status_b,
7. date_b,
8. ID_b.

Now I want to compare the first four columns with the last 4 columns that is `Name_a` with `Name_b`, `status_a` with `status_b` etc. How can I do this in spark with `scala` language?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that one record can be represented as:

```
Person(name: String, status: Boolean, date: String, id: Int)
```

In your case each row contains a double record of `Person`s. You can wrap two persons into one row as next:

```
case class Person(name: String, status: Boolean, date: String, id: Int)
case class TuplePerson(a: Person, b: Person)
```

Then you can use datasets to compare `a with b`. Here is the complete code:

```
case class Person(name: String, status: Boolean, date: String, id: Int)
case class TuplePerson(a: Person, b: Person)

val df = Seq(
(TuplePerson(Person("John", true,"15-05-2019", 54), Person("John", true,"15-05-2019", 54))),
(TuplePerson(Person("Sofia", true,"15-05-2019", 54),Person("John", true,"15-05-2019", 53))),
(TuplePerson(Person("John", true,"15-05-2019", 52), Person("John", true,"15-05-2019", 52))))
.toDS()

df.where($"a" === $"b").show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|a                           |b                           |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|[John, true, 15-05-2019, 54]|[John, true, 15-05-2019, 54]|
|[John, true, 15-05-2019, 52]|[John, true, 15-05-2019, 52]|
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Or get the difference between the left and the right part:

```
df.where($"a" =!= $"b").show(false)

+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
|a                            |b                           |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
|[Sofia, true, 15-05-2019, 54]|[John, true, 15-05-2019, 53]|
+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Mishy, this is the difference you were looking for or you meant something else?

Answer (score 1):

> Question : I want to compare the first four columns with the last 4
>   columns that is Name_a with Name_b, status_a with status_b etc. How
>   can I do this in spark with scala language.

***Option 1:*** 
Below is the way of doing this using `except` you can achieve this...

- Take all 8 columns as a dataframe
- take first 4 columns in the dataframe and alias it ... thats your first dataframe
- take last 4 columns of the dataframe and alias it with the same name as first dataframe ... that will become your second  dataframe
- using `except` you can find the differences like coded below which is self explanatory..

---

```
package com.examples
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

/**
  * @author : Ram Ghadiyaram
  */
object FindDataFrameColumnDifferences extends App with Logging {
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)

  case class Employee(Name_a: String, status_a: Int, date_a: String, ID_a: Int
                      , Name_b: String, status_b: Int, date_b: String, ID_b: Int)


  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName(this.getClass.getName).master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  //spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  import spark.implicits._
  val df = List(
    Employee("Ram", 1, "21-Mar-2019", 20048965, "Ram", 1, "21-Mar-2019", 20048965),
    Employee("Ram", 1, "21-Mar-2019", 20048965, "Ram", 1, "21-Mar-2019", 20048965),
    Employee("Mishy_tics", 1, "21-Mar-2019", 20048965, "Mishy", 1, "21-Mar-2019", 20048965),
    Employee("Mishy_tics", 1, "21-Mar-2019", 20048965, "tics", 1, "21-Mar-2019", 20048965)
  ).toDF
  logInfo("original dataframe with 8 columns")
  df.show(false)
  logInfo("Now take first 4 columns in the original dataframe and rename using alias ")
  val firstDataFrame = df.selectExpr("Name_a  as name", "status_a as status", "date_a as date", "ID_a  as id")
  logInfo("printing first dataframe ")
  firstDataFrame.show

  logInfo("Now take last 4 columns in the original dataframe and rename using alias ")
  val secondDataFrame = df.selectExpr("Name_b  as name", "status_b as status", "date_b as date", "ID_b  as id")
  logInfo("printing second dataframe ")
  secondDataFrame.show

  val columns = firstDataFrame.schema.fields.map(_.name)

  logInfo("first except second")
  var selectiveDifferences = columns.map(col => firstDataFrame.select(col).except(secondDataFrame.select(col)))

  // columns contains different values.
  selectiveDifferences.map(diff => {
    if (diff.count > 0) diff.show
  })

  selectiveDifferences = columns.map(col => secondDataFrame.select(col).except(firstDataFrame.select(col)))
  logInfo("second except first")

  // columns contains different values.
  selectiveDifferences.map(diff => {
    if (diff.count > 0) diff.show
  })
}
```

```
2019-05-05 19:10:05 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2019-05-05 19:10:13 INFO  FindDataFrameColumnDifferences:54 - original dataframe with 8 columns
+----------+--------+-----------+--------+------+--------+-----------+--------+
|Name_a    |status_a|date_a     |ID_a    |Name_b|status_b|date_b     |ID_b    |
+----------+--------+-----------+--------+------+--------+-----------+--------+
|Ram       |1       |21-Mar-2019|20048965|Ram   |1       |21-Mar-2019|20048965|
|Ram       |1       |21-Mar-2019|20048965|Ram   |1       |21-Mar-2019|20048965|
|Mishy_tics|1       |21-Mar-2019|20048965|Mishy |1       |21-Mar-2019|20048965|
|Mishy_tics|1       |21-Mar-2019|20048965|tics  |1       |21-Mar-2019|20048965|
+----------+--------+-----------+--------+------+--------+-----------+--------+

2019-05-05 19:10:13 INFO  FindDataFrameColumnDifferences:54 - Now take first 4 columns in the original dataframe and rename using alias 
2019-05-05 19:10:14 INFO  FindDataFrameColumnDifferences:54 - printing first dataframe 
+----------+------+-----------+--------+
|      name|status|       date|      id|
+----------+------+-----------+--------+
|       Ram|     1|21-Mar-2019|20048965|
|       Ram|     1|21-Mar-2019|20048965|
|Mishy_tics|     1|21-Mar-2019|20048965|
|Mishy_tics|     1|21-Mar-2019|20048965|
+----------+------+-----------+--------+

2019-05-05 19:10:14 INFO  FindDataFrameColumnDifferences:54 - Now take last 4 columns in the original dataframe and rename using alias 
2019-05-05 19:10:14 INFO  FindDataFrameColumnDifferences:54 - printing second dataframe 
+-----+------+-----------+--------+
| name|status|       date|      id|
+-----+------+-----------+--------+
|  Ram|     1|21-Mar-2019|20048965|
|  Ram|     1|21-Mar-2019|20048965|
|Mishy|     1|21-Mar-2019|20048965|
| tics|     1|21-Mar-2019|20048965|
+-----+------+-----------+--------+

2019-05-05 19:10:14 INFO  FindDataFrameColumnDifferences:54 - first except second
+----------+
|      name|
+----------+
|Mishy_tics|
+----------+

2019-05-05 19:10:29 INFO  FindDataFrameColumnDifferences:54 - second except first
+-----+
| name|
+-----+
|Mishy|
| tics|
+-----+
```

***Option 2 :***
- Another way is after making first dataframe with 8 columns using [equi join/self join on name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40356825/647053) and status ... you can find the differences between them.

See : [Joining Spark dataframes on the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343625/joining-spark-dataframes-on-the-key/40356825)

***Option 2 is simplest way I feel..***

Comment: Actually I am trying to do a CDC process , So I want the difference between the Name_a, Status_a with Name_b, Status_b. I want to capture the updates as well and that too in a go not in multiple steps

Comment: although I could not able to guess what are you doing further, divide in to 2 dataframes use second approach of joins to find out differences... please frame the question properly and formatting is very imp in order to get an answer from users. others should be able to understand your question.. please refer help of how to format a question. and provide the code snippet of what you are trying to achive .... and could not able to do it. otherwise it would be considered as low quality question..