# Lookups/filter based on two dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

We are developing a spark structured streaming application and have the below use case for transforming the data.

First dataframe:

```
Identity     input   changedInput      output     changedOutput
123          ip1     input1            op1        output1
456          ip2     input2            op2        output2
```

Second dataframe:

```
ID      incomingField  valueField    
123     ip1             1.0
789     ip3             2.0
```

I want to create a dataframe like below where I will do a lookup from second dataframe to first dataframe based the condition (secondDF.ID == firstDF.Identity && secondDF.incomingField == firstDF.input)

```
ID     incomingField    valueField   changedInput
123    ip1              1.0          input1
789    ip3              2.0          null
```

I tried using mapPartitions on second dataframe and pull data from first dataframe, but we were not able to use one dataframe in another dataframe.

Any help on this transformations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining Spark dataframes on the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343625/joining-spark-dataframes-on-the-key)

Comment: I thought of doing a join, but in my second set of iteration - my join condition will change for output field and since joins are expensive, i am thinking if we can get another alternative solution for it.